# How to access properties Resource IDs from one application to another in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am working in a project where I have several solutions. Now I am using some classes of one solution into another solution as a link. So whatever resource Id's I am adding here in these classes is showing error while compiling the solution where I am using classes as link.

For accessing resources through code I am using below sample code:

```
string textToDisplay = Properties.ResourceFilename.ID_RECOURCE_FOR_TEXT;
```

Update:

Classes which are residing in one solution and linked to another solution is using the above code for fetching text from the resource file which is present in the Properties section of the same solution where the class is reside. This Resource Id I am using for control to have several culture language(i.e. Localization) purpose.

Comment: you need to show some more code... what exactly are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: winforms or wpf? There is no problem in linking files from one project to another but the resources definition should probably be available in all projects from where you are using these resources and not only in 1 project. Show more code or explain better please...

Comment: What if you also link the resource files to the other project?

Comment: @all: what code I need to share, How will I share my company code? Please tell me what I need to share.....

Comment: @Wouter de Kort: If I am linking resource files to other projects also I need to link all Resource files because according to localization it will take strings from corresponding localization resource file

Comment: @Davide Piras: Its a wpf application but I am using this localization support in code behind that is purely C#, So I don't think there will be any difference to handle this issue in WPF as well as Winforms users

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you are trying to access a resource file in another <del>solution</del> assembly, what is not possible! To access a resource file in another <del>solution</del> assembly you need to write a accessor in that <del>solution</del> assembly that fetch the key for you. You can do this this using the `ResourceFilename.ResourceManager.getString("YOUR_ID");`

Example:

I am still not shure if we are talking about the same problem but the following example should clear this up: Guess you have a `CarTuning` resource file in a assembly named  `Car` and you need to access these in a second assembly named `Driver`. By default this is not possible and you get a `..does not exist..` error. To solve this you need to write a accessor class in the `Car` assembly that accept a string as key and uses `CarTuning.ResourceManager.GetString("KEY")` to fetch a requested Value. You cant use Static Type access except if you implementing a `switch` block in the accessor instead of the `GetString()`
Now you can get a Resource from the `Car` assembly in the `Driver` assembly using the new written accessor Class, that does the Value fetching for you.

Comment: But it is showing error in the solution where I am using the class as link: **"The name 'Properties' does not exist in the current context"**

Comment: @Turleneck I've done an update that hopefully clarify this up